# throw error after add a field in an exist entity

Tags: jhipster

there is an exist entity named student.now i used command line

```
jhipster entity student
```

to add a field birthday type of Instant.when i restart app after jhipster generate code,idea throw

> 2018-08-29 13:35:59.651 ERROR 12500 --- [mo-1-Executor-1]
>   i.g.j.c.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase   : Liquibase could not start
>   correctly, your database is NOT ready: Validation Failed:
>        1 change sets check sum
>             config/liquibase/changelog/20180829023724_added_entity_Student.xml::20180829023724-1::jhipster
>   was: 7:aba89ebafe84e997111f7ce081afc26c but is now:
>   7:7d10331a42bc3d1b3d90f86c2fc5ab2b
>
> liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
>        1 change sets check sum
>             config/liquibase/changelog/20180829023724_added_entity_Student.xml::20180829023724-1::jhipster
>   was: 7:aba89ebafe84e997111f7ce081afc26c but is now:
>   7:7d10331a42bc3d1b3d90f86c2fc5ab2b
>
> at
>   liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate(DatabaseChangeLog.java:266)
>     at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:210)   at
>   liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:192)    at
>   liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:431)
>     at
>   liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:388)
>     at
>   io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.initDb(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:103)
>     at
>   io.github.jhipster.config.liquibase.AsyncSpringLiquibase.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$0(AsyncSpringLiquibase.java:83)
>     at
>   io.github.jhipster.async.ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.lambda$createWrappedRunnable$1(ExceptionHandlingAsyncTaskExecutor.java:68)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

and i cant save a new student at all,why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jhipster liquibase validation error after modify entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43207163/jhipster-liquibase-validation-error-after-modify-entity)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216307/how-to-modify-existing-entity-generated-with-jhipster - there is a coment in the site that tells what you shuoldnt override when updating an entity, mayby this will help